# R: multiple linear regression model and prediction model

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction, lm

Starting from a linear `model1 = lm(temp~alt+sdist)` i need to develop a prediction model, where new data will come in hand  and predictions about `temp` will be made.

I have tried doing something like this:

```
model2 = predict.lm(model1, newdata=newdataset)
```

However, I am not sure this is the right way. What I would like to know here is, if this is the right way to go in order to make prediction about `temp`. Also I am a bit confused when it comes to the `newdataset`. Which values should be filled in etc.?

Comment: You can just use `predict` instead of `predict.lm` it will do the same thing. For the `newdata` you need a `data.frame` with the same predictors as the original model - in your case `alt` and `sdist`.

Comment: @JohnPaul ok i got this. the only difference is that my `newdataset` comes from a text file by `read.table`. So how what does this means? and how should i use the `data.frame`? Update your comment into an answer if you may

Comment: The object created by `read.table` will be a `data.frame` by default, so no worries there. So just do `NewDataSet<-read.table(whatever)` and then use `NewDataSet` in the `predict()` function and all should be well. This assumes that `NewDataSet` has columns named `alt` and `sdist`.

Comment: @JohnPaul Ok so i guess i am good  since what you describing above is exactly what i have done. Is there any way to verify the predictions made though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am putting everything from the comments into this answer.

1) You can use `predict` rather than `predict.lm` as `predict` will know your input is of class `lm` and do the right thing automatically.

2 The `newdataset` should be a `data.frame` with the same variables as your original predictors - in this case `alt` and `sdist`.

3) If you are bringing in you data using `read.table` by default it will create a `data.frame`. This assumes that the new data has columns named `alt` and `sdist` Then you can do:

```
NewDataSet<-read.table(whatever)
NewPredictions<- predict(model1, newdata=NewDatSet)
```

4) After you have done this if you want to check the predictions - you can do the following

```
summary(model1)
```

This will give you the intercept and the coefficients for `alt` and `sdist`
    NewDataSet[1,]
This should give you the `alt` and `sdist` values for the first row, you can change the 1 in the bracket to be any row you want. Then use the information from `summary(model1)` to calculate what the predicted value should be using any method that you trust.

Finally use 
    NewPredictions[1]
to get what `predict()` gave you for the first row (or change the 1 to any other row)

Hopefully that should all work out.